# When to and when not to use pointers in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, pointers

I know there are a lot of questions on pointers out there, particularly now for Objective-C. But I'm looking for some higher level answers to help me understand the paradigms in Objective-C.

I've heard some people say that using pointers in Objective-C is a matter or experience, i.e. some classes demand that you use pointers, others don't. Is this true? And is that the extent of using pointers in Objective-C.

Basically, apart from when you want to explicitly pass reference variable to methods, what are the rules for pointers in Objective-C?

Comment: I pretty much use a pointer for everything but primitives. If it's an `int`, `NSInteger`, `CGFloat` or anything of that sort - I don't use an asterisk. Otherwise I give it the star. Though there's probably someone who can explain it better...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You use a pointer *always* when referring to something on the heap and *sometimes, but usually not* when referring to something on the stack.

Since Objective-C objects are always allocated on the heap (with the exception of Blocks, but that is orthogonal to this discussion), you always use pointers to Objective-C objects.  Both the `id` and `Class` types are really pointers.

Where you don't use pointers are for certain *primitive types* and *simple structures*.  `NSPoint`, `NSRange`, `int`, `NSUInteger`, etc... are all *typically* accessed via the stack and *typically* you do not use pointers.

As for `Why the * in Objective-C?`, you might find this [question of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304176/objective-c-difference-between-id-and-void/1304277#1304277).

Comment: +1 thanks bbum, great answer. how do you know which types are primitive when working within the Cocoa framework. And more importantly, if do use a pointer incorrectly, will the mistake be caught at compile time?

Comment: If you cmd-double-click something in Xcode, it should take you to the definition.  If that definition is something like `Foo *bar` and you cmd-double-click the `Foo`, it'll take you to the definition of *that*.  You'll quickly get a feel for which types are what.

Comment: Well put, bbum, I've always wondered this myself, and your explanation was very clear and to the point! +1