# Message flow in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, class, messaging, subclass, delegation

Does anyone have a good reference which really outlines how this entire 'message flow' between classes, subclasses, etc.... works in Objective-C?  It seems very central to the architecture of the programming environment in Mac world and would be very helpful to understand.

Answer (score 2):

This has been covered in a number of different questions, though to answer different aspects of the question.

This question/answer, in particular, seems relevant:

[Objective-C: difference between id and void *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304176/objective-c-difference-between-id-and-void/1304277#1304277)

If you are curious as to exactly what happens at a method callsite, I wrote quite the long winded multi-part article giving an [instruction-by-instruction tour of objc_msgSend](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-part-1-the-road-map/)().