# Cannot use respondsToSelector using ARC on Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, automatic-ref-counting

When I call `respondsToSelector` in an ARC environment, I get the following error message `Automatic Reference Counting Issue` `No known instance method for selector respondsToSelector:`

This is the header

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>


@class MTScrollView;

@protocol MTScrollViewDelegate
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(MTScrollView *)scrollView;
@end


@interface MTScrollView : NSScrollView 
{

}

@property(nonatomic, weak) id<MTScrollViewDelegate>delegate;

@end
```

This is the implementation file

```
#import "MTScrollView.h"

@implementation MTScrollView

@synthesize delegate;


- (void)reflectScrolledClipView:(NSClipView *)aClipView
{
    [super reflectScrolledClipView:aClipView];

    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidScroll:)])
    {
        [delegate scrollViewDidScroll:self];
    }
}

@end
```

Any suggestions on why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 278, accepted):

Make the protocol conform to NSObject

```
@protocol MTScrollViewDelegate <NSObject>
```

Otherwise the compiler doesn't think that the object will respond to NSObject messages like `respondsToSelector`, and will generate a warning. It will succeed at runtime without issues either way.

Comment: Could anyone explain why conforming to NSObject fixes the issue?

Comment: @piobyz, `respondsToSelector` is an instance method of `NSObject` so the system needs to know that the delegate is some of subclass of `NSObject`

Comment: @David thanks, you're right, additionally here is some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304176/objective-c-difference-between-id-and-void/1304277#1304277

Comment: @piobyz in the "old world" before ARC the compiler assumed you know what you are doing and simply ignored some stuff at compile time. Now ARC manages retains and releases for you. To be able to ensure that a methods exists, the method must be found in your project. While working with id the compiler cannot find any symbols. By restricting the protocol to NSObject ARC knows exactly that any possible delegate will contain "respondsToSelector". This ensures consistency and your memory management will be always fine. Classes which aren't matching NSObject will cause an error if used as delegate.

Comment: @piobyz: Because `respondsToSelector:` is part of the NSObject protocol. The `delegate` property is declared as `id <MTScrollViewDelegate>`, which says only that the delegate responds to messages declared in that protocol. Thus, you need that protocol to conform to the NSObject protocol for the compiler to know that `respondsToSelector:` is among them.

Comment: @David: Not quite. `delegate` isn't declared with a class name, so the NSObject class is not relevant here—the compiler doesn't, and still doesn't, know that those two things are related. The “NSObject” that is part of the solution is the NSObject *protocol*, because that's where `respondsToSelector:` is declared. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/

Comment: @PeterHosey thanks for the heads-up. So I guess it's always a good idea to conform my custom protocol to at least <NSObject> protocol, the same as when subclassing NSObject?

Comment: @piobyz: Yeah. There's not really any reason not to, and it lets you use most NSObject things (everything declared in the protocol) without making the compiler suspicious.

Answer (score 5):

For Swift this becomes:

```
@objc protocol MTScrollViewDelegate: NSObjectProtocol
```

> The NSObject protocol groups methods that are fundamental to all Objective-C objects.

For more information on what NSObjectProtocol is: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html