# Xcode error: No known instance method for selector

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I need help debugging my class. I am getting an error so bizarre that I couldn't find anything similar, so I'm just going to put down most of my code.

```
//Tab.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class Tab;
@protocol TabDelegateDataSource <NSObject>
@required
-(void)removeTab:(Tab *)tab;
@end

@interface Tab : UIView
{
     id <TabDelegateDataSource> __strong _delegate;
}

@property(strong) id <TabDelegateDataSource> delegate;

-(void)removeTab;

@end

//  Tab.m
#import "Tab.h"
@implementation Tab
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
-(void)removeTab
{
    [self.delegate removeTab:self];//Error here saying: No known instance method for selector 'removeTab:'  
}

@end
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would happen if you replace `self.delegate` with `_delegate` on the offending line?

Comment: Does your delegate actually have a method `removeTab`? This error message is implying it doesn't. Try debugging and inspecting self.delegate, and make sure it is what you expect, and that it has a `removeTab` method.

Comment: the problem is not in the code you have posted. I copied it to a new project and it compiles without errors and warnings

Comment: Please post the console error message.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579337/self-delegate-respondstoselector-does-not-compile) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941051/cannot-use-respondstoselector-using-arc-on-mac) have the answer.  It has to do with NSObject

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that it was a stupid problem with Xcode I restarted the app a couple of times and it ended up working out.

Comment: I can't believe this answer work out but restart Xcode solved my problem. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 16):

I can now recreate and fix this error at will.

Make sure that the .h header where this is defined ...

```
@protocol TabDelegateDataSource <NSObject>
-(void)removeTab:(Tab *)tab;
@end
```

... **is included** wherever you plan to use the delegate, e.g. somewhere at the top of the .m source that includes this:

```
[self.delegate removeTab:self]
```

If the compiler has only seen a **forward definition** of TabDelegateDataSource like this:

```
@protocol TabDelegateDataSource;
```

You'll get the error:

```
error: no known instance method for selector 'removeTab:'
```

and not the more expected forward definition related error

Comment: This was my problem. I wasn't importing the header for my protocol in this .h file. Thank you sir !

Answer (score 4):

You should always check your delegate this way, before calling a method, even with required protocol methods:

```
if( self.delegate != nil && [ self.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector( removeTab: ) ]
{
    /* Call delegate method... */
}
```

Doing so even for required methods adds an extra-safety, as this check is made at runtime.
Someone may ignore or disable the compiler warnings, or fool the compiler with type-casts.

For instance:

```
UILabel * label        = [ [ UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame: CGRectZero ];
someTableView.delegate = ( id < UITableViewDelegate > )label;
```

Also, you may want to use `performSelector` for the actual method call:

```
[ self.delegate performSelector: @selector( removeTab: ) withObject: self ];
```

Comment: I don't see why this should be necessary for methods that are defined as required in the protocol. The compiler will show a warning if a required method is not implemented.

Comment: @Macmade  What is the rational for preferring `performSelector` over a method call?

Comment: @fluchtpunkt This is an extra safety, so you don't rely on compiler settings. See my edit, which explain the reason of the runtime check.

Comment: I get your point. But if I do something like a typecast to the wrong thing I would prefer a crash to silent malfunction. It's required for a reason. If the rest of the code works correctly without the required method it should have been declared @optional ^^

Comment: @fluchtpunkt Sure... Then simply do the check at runtime, for the extra safety, and throw an exception if it fails for a required protocol method. I know it may seem stupid, as the compiler should check this. But when you work with other people, it might get handy, as you don't control the way they code. : )

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you haven't incorrectly declared the delegate property in the interface (probably by copying and pasting from another file).  For example:

```
@protocol SomeDelegate

...

@end

@interface SomeClass

...

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<DifferentDelegate>delegate; 


@end
```

The above line will cause the "No known instance method for selector..." because of mismatch with the indtended protocol , probably a copy and paste error. Furthermore, it is likely overriding the correct reference to  from a DIFFERENT class where it actually belongs, far away from this line of code, making it hard to spot.

Correct the above declaring your property with the intended protocol:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<SomeDelegate>delegate;
```

Comment: delegates should always be weak (never retain/strong)

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I missed to declare `<NSObject>` in Protocol.

```
@protocol CustomProtocol <NSObject>
- (void)doSomethingWithSize:(CGSize)size;
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename the `delegate` to others like `delegateForTab`.

Your class `Tab` is subclassing `UIView`, so `self.delegate`'s `self` class is also a subclass of the `UIView`. `UIView` may has its own delegate(it inherits from UIResponder, and deep from NSObject), and it has not the `-(void)removeTab` method. Just my personal guess.
My solution is to **rename** it(not find the answer whether it can be subclassed either yet).

**Suggestion for using delegate**: You should implement the `protocol` and use the `delegate` in other view controllers, not in the same class that you declare it. :)

Comment: Good practice, but UIView does not have a delegate. So this won't help unfortunately... : )

Comment: @Macmade, thank you for your advice! I have happen met this issue before:I created a class that inherit from UINavigationController, resulted with same error, and I solved it by renaming the `delegate`. Just now, I refer to the SDK, the UIView doesn't have its delegate, it's right. :) However, It inherits from `UIResponder`, and deep from `NSObject`. `NSObject` has its protocol & delegate. So I think `[self.delegate removeTab:self];`'s `self` is just a NSObject. I'm not sure whether this is a true reason. Just my personal guess. :p

Answer (score 1):

Someone might needed,

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"removeTab");

if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    objc_msgSend(self.delegate, selector);
}
```

Note: Don't forget this, `#import <objc/message.h>`

Answer (score 0):

This error is not a compiler error, isn't it? Because I have no compiler errors with your code here.

So if this is a runtime error, have you declared `<TabDelegateDataSource>` in your delegate classes like this:

`@interface SomeClass : UIView <TabDelegateDataSource>`

If you did so, the compiler should be warning you if your instance method can't be found.

Or maybe you should also post the code of your delegate class for more informations.

P.S. The delegate should not be `__strong`. You'd better use `__unsafe_unretained` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I import my appdelegate.h and error resolved...