# What is the difference between a c style pointer and an id style object?

Tags: objective-c, c, object, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [objective c difference between id and void *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304176/objective-c-difference-between-id-and-void)

While reading through NSZone.h in the Foundation framework I ran across a comment mentioning something being "more like a c style pointer than an id style object". I realized I don't understand the difference.

**What is the difference between a c style pointer and an id style object?**

Comment: At the 10,000 foot level an `id` is very much similar to a `void*` pointer.  The distinction is that `id` is typed, but the type is "Objective-C object", a very large and "mushy" category.

Comment: Sorry, I read the article wrong. :( Incorrect answer deleted. Thanks for pointing that out, guys. Article here for reference: http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2008/03/id-vs-nsobject-vs-id.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A C pointer can point at anything - objects, structures, raw bytes, strings, ...

A 'id' pointer is pointing at an instance of an Objective-C object. 'id' is untyped, so it could be pointing at an instance of any class. Something like NSObject* is typed; you know what kind of object it is pointing at.

Answer (score 1):

The header appears to be talking specifically about how things are treated by the Objective-C garbage collector. Generic pointers obtained from `malloc()` are not managed by the collector, while objects are. That comment is on `NSMakeCollectable()`, a function that enables GC on CoreFoundation-style objects.