# In Objective-C, is "id" the same as "void *" in C, and how the program tell the class during method invocation?

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C, is `id` exactly the same as `void *` in C?  (a generic pointer type).

If so, when we use

```
id obj = [[Fraction alloc] init];
[obj methodName];
obj = [[ComplexNumber alloc] init];
[obj anotherMethodName];
```

When the method is called, by what way does the program know what class `obj` is?

Comment: I think this gets resolved at runtime if I'm not mistaken, caller is loaded into a register (eax I think) and then function is loaded into ecx and then obj-c does some checking to send a "message" to that object which is the method call (this can fail silently I believe) IIRC. It's been a while since I messed with/looked at obj-c internals so I may be wrong on some points. For all intents and purposes you can look at it as void * but with less restrictions in some cases

Comment: possible duplicate of [objective c difference between id and void *](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304176/objective-c-difference-between-id-and-void)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`id` is not the same as a `void *`. `id` is a pointer to an Objective C object of unknown type; like the `object` datatype of C# or Java. A `void*` can point at anything; a non-nil `id` is expected to point at a data structure that's common to all ObjC objects and contains a pointer to their respective class data.

The ObjC runtime - the implementation of `alloc`/`init`/etc. - makes sure all the valid objects have the right class pointer in them.

IIRC, in Apple's implementation the pointer-sized variable that `id` points at *is*, in fact, the pointer to the class.

In the class' data block, there's a list of methods that maps method signature to the function pointer to the method implementation. From there, it's a fairly simple lookup that happens in run time when you send a message to (i. e. call a method in) an object. Also a pointer to the base class so that the method lookup may continue up the inheritance tree.

That, by the way, is why derefencing a void pointer is a compiler error while sending messages to an `id` is legal, if statically unsafe.

Comment: Its not quite the same object in C# and Java, NSObject is the same. id is a way to tell the compiler I am going to use dynamic typing with this object, id is equivalent to var in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

`id` in Objective-C is not eactly the same as `void *` in C.

From Apple's "The Objective-C Programming Language":

```
typedef struct objc_object {
   Class isa;
} *id;
```

Which means, `id` is a pointer to an `objc_object` structure, which is different from a pointer to `void`.

> Every object thus has an `isa` variable that tells it of what class it
>   is an instance. Since the `Class` type is itself declared as a pointer.

```
typedef struct objc_class *Class;
```

And regarding, *how the program tell the class during method invocation?*, here is this from the same programming guide cited above:

> The `isa` instance variable identifies the object's **class** -what
>   kind of object it is. Objects with the same behavior (methods) and the
>   same kinds of data (instance variables) are members of the same class.
>
> Objects are thus **dynamically typed** at runtime. Whenever it needs
>   to, the runtime system can find the exact class that an object belongs
>   to, just by asking the object. (To learn more about the runtime, see
>   *Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide.*)

According to the guide, `id`, `nil`, and other basic types of Objective-C are defined in the header file `objc/objc.h`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `id` is just a generic pointer.  Class resolution at compile-time is just to inform the user of warnings and errors.  However, a veritable with a type of id will not be tied to any particular class at compile time.  The actual class will not be known until the object is accessed at runtime.  If the object is a subclass of `NSObject`, which it most likely will be, your code can asks the object what it's class is.

`[myObject class]` will return the class of `myObject`.  `[myObject isMemberOfClass:[SomeClass class]]` will return a `BOOL` indicating whiter ir not `myObject` is a member of the class `SomeClass`.

If your code calls a method on `myObject`, the runtime will attempt to make the call, even if the object does not respond to that method.  If `myObject` does not implement that method, a runtime exception will occur.

You can also ask `myObject` ahead of time to find out if the method is valid with `[myObject respondsToSelector:@selector(myCoolMethod)]`.