# Why not use NSObject while initialization instead of id

Tags: objective-c, nsobject

When a new object is created and initialized why do we use id? Can't we use (NSObject*)?

Comment: Yes, you can. Here is the [article](http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2008/03/id-vs-nsobject-vs-id.html) that explains all this things...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not every object in Objective C is `NSObject`. There are other root classes (for example, `NSProxy`), that are not derived from `NSObject`.

`id` means absolutely any object. Everything is Objective C that can receive messages (including `Class`) can be passed as `id` without type warnings.

`NSObject*` is only useful on objects that are actually derived from `NSObject`. If you pass something that is not derived from it, type checker will complain.

Comment: Almost;  one big reason why `id` is used is because it doesn't require a cast to a more specific type whereas `NSObject*` does.

Answer (score 1):

Because `NSObject` is a distinct Objective C class.  It's the base class for most *everything* (* but not everything, +1 to HamsterGene), but it's still a class.

And if you assigned a new object (of any type that *descends* from `NSObject`) to it, you'd lose the inheritence & properties of whatever subclassed type you had created were.

`id` is [roughly equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304176/objective-c-difference-between-id-and-void) to `void *` in it's behavior where you can assign any Objective C object to an `id`, like how you can assign any random chunk of memory (with no care for it's contents or type) to a `void *`.