# crash on [GetReturnValue:] method is used to obtain OC object, help me

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

Using [code 1]【 getReturnValue  :】  iOS reflection OC object, in the

【iPhone4s + iOS8.4】、【 iphone 4 + iOS7.1】 (crash),
【iPhone6 + iOS9.3】、【 iphone 5 + iOS8.4.1】 (pass),

But i implement the following [code 2] on all of  systems test pass, is that a system bug or other reson?

```
// code 1 
id objcMinor;    
if( !strcmp(minorReturnType, @encode (id)) )   
{  
　　　[invoMinor getReturnValue:&objcMinor];   
}


// code 2 
void *temp = NULL;   
[objcMinor getReturnValue:&temp];   
id objcMinor = (__bridge id)temp;   


NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dic setObject:objcMinor forKey:@"minor"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dic forKey:@"test"];
```

edit Xcode scheme->run->enable Zombile objects
console output

*** -[CFNumber release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7baa7460

crash screenshot ：[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eisKT.png)

test demo download link https://github.com/leopardpan/IssuesDemo

Comment: difference between id and void *  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304176/objective-c-difference-between-id-and-void

Comment: Someone recommended I use 【__autoreleasing id objcMinor】，I'm not sure the official recommendation should do is to do a good job.

Comment: apple link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSInvocation/getReturnValue: