# Advantage of data type id vs NSString in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, memory, nsstring

This code...

```
NSString * s = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello, World"]; 
s = s.lowercaseString;
NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

...allows the use of dot notation but is strongly typed.
This code...

```
id s = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello, World"]; 
s = [s lowercaseString];
NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

... is weakly typed and requires use of square brackets.

Other than that, is there any advantage of using one over the other?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466777/whats-the-difference-between-declaring-a-variable-id-and-nsobject/

Comment: Not really, the other questions asks about the difference between `NSObject*` and `id`. This question here asks why one should explicitly use the correct type.

Comment: @gs: They are both about Objective-C static typing and the answer to that question also answers this one. Just because one uses one class as an example and another uses a different class doesn't make them significantly different.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're creating an `NSString`, then you might as well declare it as an `NSString`, and let the compiler help you.

The point of using id is to prevent strong coupling, and to use objects whose types are not known until a later time. e.g IBAction methods include the sender as a parameter as an id, because the exact type of the object isn't known.

**Edited to add:**

You may be new to the language, so I'll mention a couple of things

Firstly, where you have `@"Hello, World"`, you already have an NSString, just one that is static. So you don't need to go through `initWithString` to create it. Just write:

```
NSString *s = @"Hello, World";
```

And, because you didn't `alloc` it, you don't have to worry about releasing it.

Secondly s.lowerCaseString. As Stephen has already answered, this is considered to be bad style. When you change a string to lower case, you aren't getting a property of the the string, you are causing an operation to be done on the string, in which case, you really should use bracket syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The compiler warns you if you try to put a `NSString` into a method that expects a `NSNumber`.

It's more likely that the compiler finds your mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

Arguably the former code is incorrect. You should only really use the dot notation to get/set properties, and `lowercaseString` is a method.

Otherwise, as you suggest, the only real difference is type safety. If you had a typo, say you put `[a loercaseString]`, the compiler wouldn't shout at you.

There are certainly cases where you'd use `id` but your example is not one of them

Comment: Oh, sorry about the typo. I just wanted to correct the first method but just as I pressed "edit" I saw `loercase` and didn't read the context.

Comment: No worries. You don't normally expect people to deliberately write typos!