# Difference between id<protocol> and NSObject<protocol>

Tags: objective-c, delegates

In Objective-C, `id<protocol> or NSObject<protocol>` are frequently used for delegate declaration.

What are the main differences between id and NSObject?
When do you want to use one versus the other?

Comment: Helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466777/whats-the-difference-between-declaring-a-variable-id-and-nsobject

Comment: This is not a duplicate, because "`id` vs `NSObject *`" and "`id<protocol> vs NSObject<protocol> *"` are significantly different questions. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Martin is right, it's not the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`id<protocol> obj` is the declaration for any object that conforms to the specified protocol.
You can send any message from the given protocol to the object (or from the protocols
that `<protocol>` inherits from).

`NSObject<protocol> *obj` is the declaration for any object that

- conforms to the given protocol, and
- is derived from `NSObject`.

That means that in the second case, you can send any methods from the `NSObject` class
to the object, for example

```
id y = [obj copy];
```

which would give a compiler error in the first case.

The second declaration also implies that `obj` conforms to the `NSObject` *protocol*.
But this makes no difference if `<protocol>` is derived from the NSObject protocol:

```
@protocol protocol <NSObject>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. So id<protocol> is the same functionally as NSObject<protocol> if protocol is derived from <NSObject>?

Comment: @Boon: No. *"This makes no difference"* applies only to the last part of the answer, that both `id<protocol> obj` and `NSObject<protocol> *obj` imply that the object conforms to the NSObject protocol. - Perhaps I should delete the last part from the answer, it makes it only more confusing.