# Why does adding a protocol (to id) cause semantic issues?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Let's say I have a trivial class like this:

```
@interface ABPair : NSObject
@property id key;
@property id value;
- (void) printSize;
@end

@implementation ABPair
- (void) printSize {
    NSLog(@"the size of your key is: %@", NSStringFromSize([self.key sizeWithAttributes: nil]));
}
@end
```

This compiles with no warnings (in Xcode 5), and runs successfully, and prints a reasonable value.

However, if I made this one change:

```
@property id<NSCopying> key;
```

then I get two compiler errors:

- ARC Semantic Issue: No known instance method for selector 'sizeWithAttributes:'
- Semantic Issue: Passing 'id' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSSize' (aka 'struct CGSize')

Why is the compiler able to identify the proper method (on NSString) when I provide no information at all about the type, but unable to identify the method when I say that the object must be of a protocol to which that class conforms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id key` declares a "generic" Objective-C variable. It can point to any object,
and the compiler accepts any messages sent to it.
If you compile with ARC, it is only required that the message signature is known
to the compiler at all (from any class).

`id<myprotocol> key` specifically declares a pointer to an object conforming to that protocol.
The compiler accepts only messages from the `<myprotocol>` protocol (or other protocols that `<myprotocol>` inherits from).

Comment: Does using `id<myproto>` essentially upgrade the `id` to `NSObject*`, then?  Is there any difference between `id<myproto>` and `NSObject<myproto>*`?

Comment: @user241221: It is not exactly the same, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567328/difference-between-idprotocol-and-nsobjectprotocol.